# java (library) can not seem to find grooy classes

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm in a complex situation, and I'm going to try to be brief but I'd happily any additional information.

I have inherited the responsibility for a massive, ancient (in Internet years), and poorly documented code base, mostly in groovy. Mercifully the vast majority of this large system of Apps and services and plugins will be "end of life"d in a few months, but there's once piece that needs to live on. I've have been trying to extract just that piece. So it can stand up on it's own.

Overall things have gone pretty well, there are some unit tests, so I've been able to use the compilation and the unit tests to figure out what class files I've needed to bring over and 3rd party libraries I've needed.

However I've run into an issue (both in the unit tests and when I try to actually "run" the application).

### The Error Message

The error message looks something like this.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
Cannot cast object '[
...
about 20 different classes, as far as I can tell these are ORM entities
...
]' with class 'com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableList' to class 'java.lang.Class' due to:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [
...
the exact same list of classes (and paths) only with the java style '/' instead of the groovy style '.'
... ]
```

To make things more complicated, even in my much smaller code base there are still a lot of dependencies (all very old).

I'm running `Groovy Version: 2.2.2 JVM: 1.7.0_121 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`

I had been running gradle 2.2.1 but after I ran into this problem I did some research and learned that I should be able to update gradle so I did, I'm now at 4.7 (that did not fix the problem).

### More Information Than You Require

I'm afraid I don't know groovy or java or gradle that well, and I understand the ecosystem even less.

In the medium term I'm planning on bringing the dependencies and environment up to versions that are currently being supported but I think it would be best to get this to work the old way first.

The original project that I cribbed all this code from still does build. The code I brought over was spread out over many different projects that were all formed a very complicated dependency tree. I figured it would be best to bring them into one project since the "new" code base is going to be much smaller.

I've spend a fair amount of time looking at the code where this error is happening (and it's stack trace), it appears as though there's a lot going on

```
     protected HibernateBundle<HohumDatabaseConfiguration> initializeHibernateBundle(List<Class<?>> serviceEntities) {
        HibernateBundle bundle = new HibernateBundle<HohumDatabaseConfiguration>(
                ImmutableList.copyOf(serviceEntities),
                new HohumSessionFactoryFactory()) {
            @Override
            DatabaseConfiguration getDatabaseConfiguration(HohumDatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
                return configuration.database
            }
        }
        return bundle
    }
```

The problematic line is `ImmutableList.copyOf(serviceEntities)`.

### Ideas

All of these Entities were in a "plugin" (I'm still not sure what a "plugin is exactly in this context). From reading the documentation I do know this was so the code could be shared with some other applications (not in this repo). Maybe in the "old" repo java has not issues finding the classes because they're all wrapped up in a nice jar by the time this casting needs to happen.

This is a bug in groovy or one of the 3rd party libraries I'm using and I should try some new versions of things and it will just start working.

(I'm not really excited about either of my ideas)

### Question

If you know how to solve this problem that would be wonderful. If not, how should one proceed?

If any important information is missing I'd be happy to supply it. Thank you so much for reading all this.

### Full Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[class us.rupe.domain.AnswerEntity, class us.rupe.domain.AnswerTagEntity, class us.rupe.domain.BundleEntity, class us.rupe.domain.BundleProductEntity, class us.rupe.domain.IdealProductEntity, class us.rupe.domain.ProductEntity, class us.rupe.domain.QuestionEntity, class us.rupe.domain.TagEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SubjectEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SubjectDependentEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SurveyEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SurveyInstanceEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SurveyInstanceAnswerEntity, class us.rupe.domain.SurveyQuestionEntity, class us.rupe.domain.PurchaseEntity, class us.rupe.domain.QuestionGuardEntity, class us.rupe.domain.RecommenderVersionEntity, class us.rupe.domain.AdjusterConfigurationEntity, class us.rupe.domain.CurrentAdjusterConfigurationEntity]' with class 'com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableList' to class 'java.lang.Class' due to: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [class us/rupe/domain/AnswerEntity, class us/rupe/domain/AnswerTagEntity, class us/rupe/domain/BundleEntity, class us/rupe/domain/BundleProductEntity, class us/rupe/domain/IdealProductEntity, class us/rupe/domain/ProductEntity, class us/rupe/domain/QuestionEntity, class us/rupe/domain/TagEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SubjectEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SubjectDependentEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SurveyEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SurveyInstanceEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SurveyInstanceAnswerEntity, class us/rupe/domain/SurveyQuestionEntity, class us/rupe/domain/PurchaseEntity, class us/rupe/domain/QuestionGuardEntity, class us/rupe/domain/RecommenderVersionEntity, class us/rupe/domain/AdjusterConfigurationEntity, class us/rupe/domain/CurrentAdjusterConfigurationEntity]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToClass(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:380)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:249)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
    at us.rupe.service.HohumDatabaseService$1.<init>(HohumDatabaseService.groovy)
    at us.rupe.service.HohumDatabaseService.initializeHibernateBundle(HohumDatabaseService.groovy:57)
    at us.rupe.service.HohumDatabaseService.<init>(BloomDatabaseService.groovy:25)
    at us.rupe.RecommendationService.<init>(RecommendationService.groovy)
    at us.rupe.RecommendationService.main(RecommendationService.groovy:58)
```

Comment: could you add full stacktrace to your question?

Comment: @daggett Sure thing.

Comment: the `HohumDatabaseService` class where `initializeHibernateBundle` located looks like the pure java class. you could try to add `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` as `HohumDatabaseService` class annotation, so possible you'll see some errors during compilation of the groovy class.

Comment: @daggett Thanks for you suggestion. However `HohumDatabaseService` already has `@groovy.transform.CompileStatic` as a class annotation.